# "Stopped Unexpectedly" tried 10000 times to fix

Tags: android, listview

here is my Main java file, MainActivity.java

```
package com.myprojects.schecklist;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private String[] items = { "Activity1", "Activity2" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

    }
}
```

and here it is  activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myprojects.schecklist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

At least i tried 4-5 methods fix that problem. At last i tried **Project>Clear** and its not fixed too. 
I tried everything and at least i'm working on it about 3days. What's wrong? I'm gonna be crazy.

Comment: it's hard to fix without looking in the logcat view. but the problem is probably your ListView id. If you're using a ListActivity , then the ListView id should be @android:id/list.

Comment: try with Activity instead of ListActivity.

Comment: Everything is fine only extend with `Activity` instead of `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
```

with:

```
 new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Extending `ListActivity` try extending `Activity` or change your

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

to

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```