# unfotunatly the application stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [detail of list item in another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433303/detail-of-list-item-in-another-screen)

When I select an item I want the application to navigate to the second activity and take a value of selected item and the related link to the TextView which exists in the second activity. The code should work but when I run it the emulator gives me a message saying "Unfortunately the application stopped". I don't know what to do to make it work?

```
public class LastActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static List<String> links;
    List<String> names;


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String link=links.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Details.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",names.get(position));
        intent.putExtra("url",link);
        Log.e("n",names.get(position)+"."+ link );
        startActivity(intent);


    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        links=new ArrayList<String>();
        names=new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            URL url=new URL(webservice);
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
            boolean insideItem = false;


                    // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {


                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                            insideItem = true;

                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {

                            if (insideItem)

                                names.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline

                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {

                            if (insideItem)

                                links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article

                        }
                    }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){

                        insideItem=false;

                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element

                }


        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

                setListAdapter(adapter);

 }
    private InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
             return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                   return null;
            }

    }

}
```

//second class or acticvites

```
public class Details extends LastActivity{
    LastActivity last=new LastActivity();
    TextView tv;
    TextView url;
    String read;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);

        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        url=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
        Intent intent=getIntent();

            // receiving  data
            String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
            String path=intent.getStringExtra("links");

            Log.e("Second Screen", name + "." + path);
            tv.setText(name);
            url.setText(path);
    }
```

Comment: what's the logcat error report?

Comment: Please take some time to read your question again before submitting it. Your language and the typos where a bit too much. Put some work into the question and the we will put some work in our answers.

Comment: threaded=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)

Comment: @user1404380: the whole log cat with red lines :)

Comment: 07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

Comment: @user1404380 If you ever need to post a logs in the future please edit your question and paste them in there (with code formatting) instead of putting them as comments. They'll be easier to read, and thus you'll be more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with passing putExtra values in the intents. Check your first Activity, you have used the key as "url", but in the details Activity you are using "links" as the key. So you are getting null Pointer Exception. Change it properly.

```
    intent.putExtra("name",names.get(position));
    intent.putExtra("url",link);
```

in Details Activity,

```
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String path=intent.getStringExtra("url");
```

instead of,

```
String path=intent.getStringExtra("links");
```

In your First Activity you have exntended ListActivty, try to replace it with Activity alone.

Or change your ListView id to @android:list in your xml file.

For more info, look at this question , ["Stopped Unexpectedly" tried 10000 times to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502484/stopped-unexpectedly-tried-10000-times-to-fix/11502568#11502568)

And also check this for more idea,

[Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=java.lang.RuntimeException:%20Your%20content%20must%20have%20a%20ListView%20whose%20id%20attribute%20is%20%27android.R.id.list)

Comment: I changed it but still same problem:(

Comment: post the logcat full detail about the error. It is not possible to tell without it.

Comment: Also check whether you have added your second activity to your manifest file or not.

Comment: 07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

Comment: This is not the one. Your logcat will have a line which has your package and your class name. We need that line

Comment: I dont know what is this can u tell me whre can i find this line??

Comment: why don't you simply copy all the red colored lines from your logcat and post it? scroll above to find if there are some other red lines prsent there.

Comment: 07-16 11:41:25.894: D/AndroidRuntime(694): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.last/com.me.last.LastActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)

Comment: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Comment: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)

Comment: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at com.me.last.LastActivity.onCreate(LastActivity.java:46)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

Comment: 07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718):  ... 11 more

Comment: i think this line which u asked about :7-16 11:41:28.534: E/AndroidRuntime(718): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.last/com.me.last.LastActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: yes. that's the exact line. See my edited answer and ask any further doubts.

Comment: when change extends ListActivity to Activity it's gaves me error at onCreat method

Comment: is that because of  overridden from the ListActivity??

Comment: I am not sure. Did u try the other option, by changing the id of your listview in XML?

Comment: i did now but when i click item it gaves me this bug 07-16 13:06:50.805: E/n(851): ????? ????? ????.http://82.212.89.6:888